# Concatenate incrementing ID to @DropDownListFor id value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to concatenate an dynamic numeric ID value to the `@DropDownListFor` HTMLHelper `Id` in my view.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AttributeValueList.Count(); i++)
{    
 ... Other code here 
<tr>
    <td class="DisplayFieldName">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AttributeValueList[i].ListingTypeID)
    </td>
    <td class="DisplayFieldData" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AttributeValueList[i].ListingTypeID, Model.AttributeValueList[i].ListingTypes, new { @id = "listDropdown", @Name = "ListingTypeID", style = "width:207px;font-size:10pt;" })            
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I can add it in the regulare HTML like so.

```
<tr class="@("listingOption-" + Model.AttributeValueList[i].ItemReschedualeOptionID)">
```

but when I try and add it inline with the HtmlHelper it errors out. Maybe I dont have the correct syntax.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AttributeValueList[i].ListingTypeID, Model.AttributeValueList[i].ListingTypes, new { @id = "listDropdown-" + ADD ID HERE, @Name = "ListingTypeID", style = "width:207px;font-size:10pt;" })
```

Ive looked at other SO post and nothing seems to work.

Here is what I've tried.

```
@id = "listDropdown-" + Model.AttributeValueList[i].ItemReschedualeOptionID,
@id = "@("listDropdown-"Model.AttributeValueList[i].ItemReschedualeOptionID)",
@id = "listDropdown-@(Model.AttributeValueList[i].ItemReschedualeOptionID)",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax to concatenate to values in HTMLHelpers

```
@id = "listDropdown-"+@Model.AttributeValueList[i].ItemReschedualeOptionID,
```